# True/False "The number of cycles in a bipartite graph may be odd"

Tags: algorithm, graph, bipartite

I have a statement.

"The number of cycles in a bipartite graph may be odd"

I think it is 'false' because the number of cycles in a bipartite can be even or odd. For example,

The below bipartite graph(first piture) has just 1 cycle (odd).

[image]

And this one(second picture) has 2 cycles (even)

[image]

So, is it right to say the statement is 'false'?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't asking if the LENGTH of the cycles can be odd?

Comment: If they may be both, they certainly may be one of them. The statement is true.

Comment: yes, not length, so that's why I'm suffering not.

Comment: @shashack That would make more sense. But it sounds like a test or hw question that tries to confuse you on purpose.

Comment: Oh my god, may be.. I don't want to take reading exam. so sad..

Comment: Anyway, thank you guys for the answering
(the statement is one of the previous exam problems.)

Comment: "may be odd" doesn't mean it can't be even.  You have proven the statement true with your first example.

Answer (score 0):

TRUE.

The number of cycles in a bipartite graph may be odd or even.

However, if a graph is bipartite, it cannot contain an odd cycle.